# How to make conditional DataTrigger in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I wanna make coloring `DataGridRow` in my datagrid using `style` in WPF. I wanna make percentage of coloring based on value. If I have value binding `Error` between 0 and 50 it will be red. And if vice versa it will be colored as Green

But How I can do with style?

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Error}" Value="Error>50"> //maybe something like this
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE08F8F" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Error}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF6DBB6D" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Comment: `WPF` `Triggers` only offer `Equality` comparison.   You're best of using `Converter` to return 1 or 0 or true or false and based on that change the colour of your row. Otherwise you will have to implement `DataTrigger` for every single value. HTH

Comment: Can you give me a sample of using `Converter` ?

Comment: While the answers posted shows a single equality operation, remember you can always go for a `IMultiValueConverter` and also be able to pass the operation you want to perform to the converter. So you could check for <,>,<=,>=,!= and sorts. You'd use a multi value converter to pass in the binding value, check against value and the operation. All three and keep the converter generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the most flexible solution will be to add some kind of `ErrorToColor` converter. Then use this XAML:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" >
    <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Error, Converter={StaticResource errorToColorConverter}}" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Such converter could look like this:

```
public class IntToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        return value is int && ((int)value) > 50 ? Colors.Green : Colors.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This way you can easily manage colors for different error values.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a custom converter that will convert `Error` to some value indicating the error state; the following converter will return `True` when `Error` is greater than 50:

```
public class ErrorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToInt(value) > 50;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now reference this in the resources (and `True` helper, you might not need this, can't remember if the conversion is automatic):

```
<system:Boolean x:Key="True">True</system:Boolean>
<local:ErrorConverter x:Key="ErrorConverter">
```

And bind it up like this:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger 
            Binding="{Binding Error, Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter}}" 
            Value="{StaticResource True}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE08F8F" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Error}" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF6DBB6D" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Something along those lines should work.

Comment: Yes you don't need `<system:Boolean x:Key="True">True</system:Boolean>` can just specify `Value="True"` also since the OP is passing `50` from xaml, you'd prolly want to pass that number as a `ConverterParameter` than hardcoding that inside the converter